# Com port disable and Windows Logs

Tags: windows-7, logging, serial-port

We have a situation where COM3 is being disabled intermittently, and has to be manually re-enabled in Device Manager.  I'm trying to track down the source in Windows 7 logs, but I don't know which logs track serial port status changes.  When I research the subject online, the only references I find are for port blocking and Windows Firewall Logs.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A starting point might be under the device properties (in Device Manager), Events tab. If you click `View All Events...` from there, you get tossed into the appropriate Event Viewer custom view.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Unfortunately we dont have that option. I looked it up and it was added in Win8.